# Why is an external document resolved in Altova XMLSpy but not in SaxonHE10?

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I want to load an external XML-document into a variable, which works in Altova XMLSpy but not in SaxonHE10.

In Altova XMLSpy the following XSLT 2.0 line returns `true`.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="fn:doc-available('https://www.xrepository.de/api/version_codeliste/urn:de:bund:destatis:bevoelkerungsstatistik:schluessel:staat_2019-02-01/genericode')"/>
```

In my local SaxonHE10 installation it returns `false`.

Are there any commandline parameters I can use to change this behavior?

Addition 18.10.2021 13:12:
The comment section ist to small, so I edit my question:
That is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:xdf3="urn:xoev-de:fim:standard:xdatenfelder_3.0.0" 
    xmlns:gc="http://docs.oasis-open.org/codelist/ns/genericode/1.0/" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="html"
>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:message>
            <xsl:copy-of select="fn:doc-available('https://www.xrepository.de/api/version_codeliste/urn:de:bund:destatis:bevoelkerungsstatistik:schluessel:staat_2019-02-01/genericode')"/>
        </xsl:message> 
        <xsl:message>
            <xsl:copy-of select="fn:document('https://www.xrepository.de/api/version_codeliste/urn:de:bund:destatis:bevoelkerungsstatistik:schluessel:staat_2019-02-01/genericode')"/>                                  
        </xsl:message> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That is the command call:

```
"C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE10.2N\bin\Transform.exe" -s:test.xml -xsl:test.xsl
```

This is the result:

```
false
Error FODC0002 while evaluating xsl:message at line 20 of file:/C:/Users/Volker/Dropbox/FIM/Tools/QS%20Datenfelder/test.xsl: Document has been marked not available: https://www.xrepository.de/api/version_codeliste/urn:de:bund:destatis:bevoelkerungsstatistik:schluessel:staat_2019-02-01/genericode
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: it is working for me, when I run that against Saxon HE. Can you provide more details about how you are invoking, or a more complete stylesheet? `java -jar saxon-he-10.5.jar -s:test.xsl -xsl:test.xsl` returns: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>true` for me when I put that copy inside of a root template.

Comment: Saxon basically relies on the JVM to establish a connection (URL.openConnection(), if I recall). There are various things you can configure regarding HTTP access at the Java level, or failing that, you can write your own URIResolver. But it would be a good idea to explore first why it is failing. Unfortunately doc-available() only gives you a yes/no answer. Putting in an HTTP traffic monitor such as Charles might help.

Comment: Is that Saxon Java or Saxon .NET that fails for you?

Comment: I get true for Saxon 10.6 HE Java and false for Saxon HE 10.6 .NET. There were some issues with TLS versions not enabled in IKVM's JVM (https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/7108), but I am not sure that is the cause here.

Comment: thanks for the quick reactions so far - I expanded the questions due to your comments

Comment: due to your suggestions I tried Saxon 10.6 HE Java - there are no errors and it works as expected

unfortuanetly this doesn't make it easier, because I share the XSLT in a community where I cannot force the decision between Java an .NET

Comment: It is hard to get to the core of the issue, as I said, Saxon 10 on .NET relies on IKVM 8 which includes some old, openjdk 8.something release I think. My guess it that some HTTP or other network protocol stuff works differently in that JDK. Whether there are some configuration settings you can easily add to your app.config to have IKVM work or whether it is kind of an error that would need an update to IKVM, an abandoned project, I am afraid, so not much hope there, is something I can't tell.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly the doc and doc-available calls to the given URL work in the Saxon .NET based XSLT fiddle app I run.

As far as I can tell, the only IKVM setting I have there in the web.config (that might as well work in an app.config for non web use of .NET and Saxon) are the TLS settings e.g.

```
<configuration>
  
  <appSettings>

    <add key="ikvm:https.protocols" value="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

So that would be worth a try, that any .NET users of Saxon for which the URI fails add the above setting to the app.config or web.config.

I now tried some simple C# code using Saxon HE 10.6 .NET with e.g.

```
        Processor processor = new Processor();

        string xpathExpression = "doc-available('https://www.xrepository.de/api/version_codeliste/urn:de:bund:destatis:bevoelkerungsstatistik:schluessel:staat_2019-02-01/genericode')";

        Console.WriteLine(processor.NewXPathCompiler().EvaluateSingle(xpathExpression, null).GetStringValue());

        Console.ReadLine();
```

**without** any change to IKVM settings or app.config this outputs true. It turns out that the used .NET framework version is decisive or part of the reason, the first test was done with 4.8. Using 4.5 gives false, using 4.6 gives true.

Even without using Saxon or IKVM, a .NET framework 4.5 application doing

```
       string url = "https://www.xrepository.de/api/version_codeliste/urn:de:bund:destatis:bevoelkerungsstatistik:schluessel:staat_2019-02-01/genericode";

        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        {
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", response.StatusCode);
                response.Close();
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

fails to establish a connection as it gives some error about not being able to establish a protected SSL/TLS channel. Using .NET framework 4.8 no such problem arises. Still don't know how to get compiled and installed .exe files like Transform.exe or Query.exe from Saxon to switch/look for the latest/highest installed .NET framework instead of (I presume) the lowest they were compiled for and tested for to run with. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls might give some clues.

Comment: I would like to try your suggestion, but I don't know how.

Comment: @Volker, do you or your stylesheet users run Saxon 10 .NET from the command line? Or using .NET/C# code?

Comment: I use the command line - therefore I tried three variants of saving a config file

Comment: directory C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE10.2N\bin:
**app.config**
IKVM.OpenJDK.Charsets.dll
IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll
IKVM.OpenJDK.Text.dll
IKVM.OpenJDK.Util.dll
IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.API.dll
IKVM.Runtime.dll
Query.exe
saxon-he-10.2.dll
saxon-he-api-10.2.dll
saxon-he-api-10.2.xml
Transform.exe
**Transform.exe.config**
**web.config**

Comment: Of course this is an answer. The question was "why doesn't it work in Saxon" and the answer is "because it doesn't work in .NET 4.5". There are supplementary questions possible, like "why doesn't it work in .NET 4.5", or "so what do I do next?", but the question as asked has been answered.

Comment: @MichaelKay, if your comment from some minutes ago relates to the "disclaimer" about commenting in an answer I had in the original attempt, I have taken that out now, it was certainly true in the first edits of an attempt to investigate the issue but that investigation kind of at least resulted in an explanation why it doesn't work; still don't know how to force the installed Transform.exe of Saxon to use 4.8 but that is another issue.

Comment: How to force Saxon to use 4.8: I would love to know. .NET versioning has always been something of a mystery to me.